# Cumulative Distribution Functions and Continuity

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, probability

The CDF is defined as $$F(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{x} f$$

Where $f$ is the pdf for a random variable $X$. I have been taught that if $X$ is a continuous random variable, then $P(X = b) = 0$.

I present the following example

> [image]

According to wikiapedia, if I want to find $P(X = 1)$, I use

$$P(X = b) = F(b) - \lim_{x \to b^-} F(x)$$

According to the formula above, it is equivalent to

$$P(X = b) = \int_{-\infty}^{b} f - \lim_{x \to b^-} \int_{-\infty}^{x} f$$

With reference to the pictures (or not?), does the above equation actually mean we are finding the area of a very small rectangle?

That is $\int_{-\infty}^{1} f$ gives us the "complete" area of the triangle at $x = 1$ and $\lim_{x \to 1^-} \int_{-\infty}^{x} f$ gives us the "same" area, but just a bit to the left of $x = 1$. Their difference gives us a very thin rectangle

Comment: Your pdf isn't a valid pdf. Note that:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty f dx = \int_0^{1/4} (1/2)dx + \int_{1/4}^{1/2} (3/2)dx= 1/8 + 3/8 = 1/2 \neq 1
$$

Comment: Wait a moment. I will create another example that works. Just give me 2 minutes

Comment: @Adriano PDF has some delta diracs that OP haven't written them!

Comment: This one should work

Answer (score 1):

Note that the Wikipedia formula:

> $$
> P(X = b) = F(b) - \lim_{x \to b^-} F(x)
> $$

only really comes in handy if the distribution of $X$ is discontinuous at $b$. You'll notice, however, that your edited CDF is now continuous everywhere, which means that for any $b\in \Bbb{R}$:
$$
P(X = b) = F(b) - \lim_{x \to b^-} F(x) = F(b) - F(b) = 0
$$
which makes sense, since $X$ is a continuous random variable.

Comment: My previous $X$ is not a continuous random variable? Which makes its pdf not continuous too? I haven't touched the direc delta "function" for too long to comment on its continuity.

Comment: Think of the formula as measuring the size of the jump discontinuity between $\lim_{x\to b^-}F(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to b^+}F(x)$

Comment: @sidht The PDF of a continuous random variable need not be continuous, only its CDF.

Comment: @Did, would you like to post that as an answer?

Comment: @sidht Done. $ $

Answer (score 1):

The PDF of a continuous random variable need not be continuous, only its CDF.

**Latest news!** The OP is in fact interested in the CDF $F$ such that $F(x)=\frac12x$ if $0\leqslant x\lt\frac14$, $F(x)=\frac32x$ if $\frac14\leqslant x\lt\frac12$, and $F(x)=1$ if $x\geqslant\frac12$. Thus $F$ has two jumps, each of height $\frac14$, at $x=\frac14$ and at $x=\frac12$. The sum of the sizes of these jumps is $\frac12\lt1$ hence the distribution of $X$ has also an absolutely continuous part, spread on $[0,\frac12]$, whose total mass is $1-\frac12=\frac12$. Thus, the distribution of $X$ is neither purely discrete nor purely absolutely continuous.

This phenomenon is hardly exotic (despite the efforts many presentations of the probabilistic apparatus make to hide it). Consider for example, what might be the simplest continuous random variable, namely, $U$ uniform on $[0,1]$. Then the distribution of $Y=\max(\frac13,U)$ is neither purely discrete nor purely absolutely continuous.

Likewise, to get some random variable $X$ with CDF $F$, consider $X=g(U)$, where $g(u)=2u$ if $0\leqslant u\lt\frac18$, $g(u)=\frac14$ if $\frac18\leqslant u\lt\frac38$, $g(u)=\frac23u$ if $\frac38\leqslant u\lt\frac34$, and $g(u)=\frac12$ if $\frac34\leqslant u\leqslant1$.

Comment: There is one bit of mystery left. Can I assume, from your comment (answer), that the CDF I have presented is actually one for a discrete r.v?

Comment: This CDF being continuous corresponds to a random variable with no discrete part at all. Once again, the dis/continuity of the PDF is irrelevant.

Comment: Oh wait, sorry I thought I had edited this CDF out. I will show you the CDF I meant

Comment: The $\max(1/3, U)$ is a number, isn't that discrete?

Comment: No. $\max(\frac13,U)$ is always in $[\frac13,1]$ and is not purely discrete. Say, what is your definition of being *discrete*?

Comment: Okay, I've thought about this with myself for a while. My definition of discrete is that for each value, you map it to EXACTLY one value. The range of your random variable is a finite set. When you take the maximum over $U$, you have many "max" which contributes to the "continuous" part of the random variable. Am I correct?

Comment: Why [reinvent the wheel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable)? Discrete random variables are those who take on either a finite or at most a countably infinite set of values. The range of $\max(\frac13,U)$ is the interval $[\frac13,1]$ hence $\max(\frac13,U)$ is not discrete.

Comment: Then what is the "discrete" part of this random variable?

Comment: The discrete part is $\frac13$ times the Dirac measure at point $\frac13$. The continuous part is $\frac23$ times the uniform distribution on the interval $(\frac13,1)$.